# How to add search tags in an activity in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android

I want all the search entries entered by user to be displayed as tags which can be removed if the user wishes,i.e.,each tag has a cross button which when pressed deletes the tag(the search entry). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html
What about search, you should create customSearch and show it when you want to find something.